# Get the current url but without the http:// part bookmarklet!

Tags: javascript, url, bookmarklet, host

Guys I have a question, hoping you can help me out with this one. I have a bookmarklet;

```
javascript:q=(document.location.href);void(open('http://other.example.com/search.php?search='+location.href,'_self ','resizable,location,menubar,toolbar,scrollbars,status'));
```

which takes URL of the current webpage and search for it in another website. When I use this bookmarklet it takes the whole URL including `http://` and searches for it. But now I would like to change this bookmarklet so it will take only the `www.example.com` or just `example.com` (without `http://`) and search for this url. Is it possible to do this and can you please help me with this one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 32):

JavaScript can access the current URL in parts. For this URL:

http://css-tricks.com/example/index.html

```
window.location.protocol = "http"

window.location.host = "css-tricks.com"

window.location.pathname = "/example/index.html"
```

please check: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/

Comment: Thanks pretty straight forward and simple :)

Answer (score 13):

This should do it

```
location.href.replace(/https?:\/\//i, "")
```

Comment: This works 99% of the time. However it doesn't work if the current Url is e.g. `http://somesite.com/query=http://someothersite.com/blahblah`. All instances of "http://" will be replaced not just the first occurance. Doesn't work for 'https://' too.

Comment: Fixed it. Handles http/https + caseinsensitve matching. Also replaces only first occurrence.

Answer (score 4):

Use `document.location.host` instead of `document.location.href`. That contains only the host name and not the full URL.

Comment: I am not sure why in the world everyone suggests regular expressions when the location object already does it for you as Gumbo suggested. Documentation is a great thing: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location

Comment: Oh yes, it is easier to use "str =  location.host + location.path + location.search". How about port number?

Comment: @o.k.w: Bostjan apparently just wants to know the host and not the full URL.

Answer (score 0):

## Use the URL api

A modern way to get a part of the URL can be to make a URL object from the url that you are given.

```
const { hostname } = new URL('https://www.some-site.com/test'); // www.some-site.com
```

You can of course just pass window location or any other url as an argument to the URL constructor.

Like this

```
const { hostname } = new URL(document.location.href);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using javascript `replace` via regex matching:

```
javascript:q=(document.location.href.replace(/(https?|file):\/\//,''));void(open('http://website.com/search.php?search='+q,'_self ','resizable,location,menubar,toolbar,scrollbars,status'));
```

Replace (https?|file) with your choice, e.g. ftp, gopher, telnet etc.

Comment: actually this won't work for file as that protocol uses three slashes

Comment: @jitter: "file" wasn't supposed to be included, it has no practical usage. It was added while I was testing the code locally on my machine. Anyway, doesn't really matter :)